# Selenium Python: Cannot click on class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, hyperlink

For my internship I need to read Data from the electricity stock market and automatically write it to an excel file.

The problem is that I need to press the button "Jahr" which is not a normal button but sth. else maybe javascript... and I am new to web scaping.

And it is also confusing that I cannot access the data in the table any more after changing the date. So I commented it on the bottom, but there I want to read the data from the table after entering the day before and clicking on "Jahr".

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\bin\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.eex.com/de/marktdaten/strom/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20German%20Power%20Future%22%7D');
time.sleep(3) 

abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div[10]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')

# print(abrechnungspreis.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
price0 = abrechnungspreis.get_attribute('outerHTML')
price1 = price0.split('<')
price2 = price1[1].split('>')
price = price2[1]


input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div[10]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')
print('Tages Abrechnungspreis vom '+input_date.get_attribute('value')+ ' ist ' + price)
# delete old date and put yesterday
input_date.send_keys('\ue003')
input_date.send_keys('\ue003')
input_date.send_keys('\ue003')
input_date.send_keys('\ue003')
input_date.send_keys('\ue003')
input_date.send_keys("03-09") # automatise later
input_date.send_keys(u'\ue007')
input_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div[10]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')
print(input_date.get_attribute('value'))

button_Jahr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div[10]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]')
print(button_Jahr.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
button_Jahr.click()

# abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div[10]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
# print(abrechnungspreis.get_attribute('value'))
# price0 = abrechnungspreis.get_attribute('outerHTML')
# price1 = price0.split('<')
# price2 = price1[1].split('>')
# price = price2[1]
print('Jahres Abrechnungspreis vom '+input_date.get_attribute('value')+ ' ist ' + price)

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

This is the error output:

```
*ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button">...</div> is not clickable at point (777, 260). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p> (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)*
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```py
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button_Jahr)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could use simpler `xpath`

```py
input_date  = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]//input')

button_Jahr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]//div[text()="Jahr"]')
```

Or first get only header and later use it with xpath which starts with `.` to create relative xpath

```py
header = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]')

# relative to header

input_date  = header.find_element_by_xpath('.//input')

button_Jahr = header.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[text()="Jahr"]')
```

And for table

```
abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//div[@id="snippet-8"]//table[1]//tr[1]/td[4]')
```

---

And you can get `price` simpler

```
price = abrechnungspreis.text
```

---

Update text

```
input_date.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE*5)
input_date.send_keys("03-09")
input_date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or

```
input_date.clear()
input_date.send_keys("2022-03-01")
input_date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

---

Full code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

url = 'https://www.eex.com/de/marktdaten/strom/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20German%20Power%20Future%22%7D'

##driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\bin\chromedriver.exe')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3) 

abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="snippet-8"]//table[1]//tr[1]/td[4]')
price = abrechnungspreis.text

header = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]')

input_date = header.find_element(By.XPATH, './/input')
date = input_date.get_attribute('value')
print(f'Tages Abrechnungspreis vom {date} ist {price}')

# --- date ---

input_date.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE*5)
input_date.send_keys("03-09")
input_date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#input_date.clear()
#input_date.send_keys("2022-03-01")
#input_date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(3)  # javascript may need time to update HTML

# find again after updating HTML 
abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="snippet-8"]//table[1]//tr[1]/td[4]')
price = abrechnungspreis.text

date = input_date.get_attribute('value')
print(f'Tages Abrechnungspreis vom {date} ist {price}')

# --- Jahr ---

button_Jahr = header.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[text()="Jahr"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button_Jahr)
time.sleep(3)  # javascript may need time to update HTML

# find again after updating HTML 
abrechnungspreis = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="snippet-8"]//table[1]//tr[1]/td[4]')
price = abrechnungspreis.text

print(f'Jahres Abrechnungspreis vom {date} ist {price}')
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Tages Abrechnungspreis vom 2022-03-11 ist 80.44
Tages Abrechnungspreis vom 2022-03-09 ist 446.25
Jahres Abrechnungspreis vom 2022-03-09 ist 173.41
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now I can solve the rest... but I don't understand how you get the shorter XPATH from the website. You have: 

button_Jahr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]//div[text()="Jahr"]') 

when I copy the short XPATH from the "Jahr" button I get sth. slightly different: //*[@id="symbolheader_pfpde"]/div/div[2]/div[6]

Comment: I didn't copy, I created them manually. I searched unique element(s) in tag or its parent(s)